# how to modularize a function that relies on a variable outside its body

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I just finished my website and now I want to refactor it by putting each function into its own `.js` file. The problem is, most of these function relies on variables like this:

```js
const App = {
  num1: 1,
  num2: 2,
  add(){
    return num1 + num2
  },
  subract(){
    return num1 - num2
  }
}
```

I want to put my `add()` & `subtract()` function inside its own `.js` file but both are relying on `num1` & `num2` variables.

One solution that I can think of is by creating an `object` that holds those `vars` and importing that object inside the .js file of each function like this:

```js
//inside add.js
import { num1, num2 } from "./globalVars";


function add(){
  return num1 + num2
} 


export default add;
```

is there a better solution for this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables just write

```
var num1, num2
```

In the head of your project and they will be available in the whole projects, but it's also not the best solution
It would be better to pass all parametrs in functions

```
function add(num1, num2){
    return num1 + num2
}
```

And if you need to work with context, you can bind it in functions

```
function add(){
    return this.num1 + this.num2
}
```

And to bind context and call the function write

```
add.call({num1: 4, num2: '20'}) // But you need num1 and num2 because they are used in "this" in add function
```